# Ordering LinQ c#

Tags: c#, linq

im trying to order my LINQ by the date value showing first today's date and the counting down but in my actual LINQ the values are not arranged they all come sometimes ordered by day and sometimes by month but never from today's date

This is my LINQ:

```
foreach (var item in db.VENTA_PLATILLOS.Select(l => l.Fecha)
         .Distinct().OrderByDescending(x => x.Month == result.Month && x.Day == result.Day))
{
    dateday = item.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    var listItem = new SelectListItem { Value = dateday, Text = dateday };
    listItem.Selected = result.Day == item.Day;
    listdate.Add(listItem);
}
```

How can i order them correctly by actual date first?

EDIT********

Values comes from a Datetime Model Variable i wil add some examples of dates:

```
2016-11-06 00:00:00.000
2016-11-05 00:00:00.000
2016-11-04 00:00:00.000
2016-11-03 00:00:00.000
2016-11-02 00:00:00.000
2016-10-31 00:00:00.000
2016-10-29 00:00:00.000
```

like this

EDIT 2 *****

GOT IT FIXED NOW
Ordering by Month and then by day finally worked after making some changes to my model

Comment: `x.Month == result.Month && x.Day == result.Day` evaluates to `true`/`false`.  You're ordering by a boolean, not the date.

Comment: Why can't he just do `OrderByDescending(x => x)`? Ins't `Fecha` a DateTime?

Comment: @StackOverflower, I think you are right, he doesn't need any trick, just OrderByDescending( x => x).

Comment: OrderByDescending(x => x) still gets me the values ordered by a matching day and month being 2016-10-10 first :/

Comment: what is result? is it today date?

Comment: Use ThenByDescending after OrderByDescending. Think u get it.

Comment: my results are ordering like this:"2016-10-01", "2016,11-02", "2016-10-02", "2016-10-03" and so on

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Month)
        .ThenByDescending(x => x.Day)
```

LINQ offers `ThenByDescending` which will allow you to order after an initial order.

But you should be able to just do this

`.OrderByDescending(x => x)` because you're already iterating over a datetime.

Comment: stil my first value shown is "2016-10-10", then they are ordering by matching month and then day countdown like "10-10","09-09"
:/ how can i fix this?

Comment: I'm not understanding what is wrong. Can you give me some dates and how this does not solve it by ordering by them?

Comment: Also if you could tell me the properties on which you're iterating over. Is it Month Day Year, or do you have a date property?

Comment: Using month and day you wouldn't be ordering by date, but just by month and day (ie: 2017/01/01 would come before 2016/02/01). Include the year, thus simply order by date.

Comment: @ArturoMartinez did you try the second suggestion made in my post? If it works, kindly accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you just need to order by x as Stackoverflower noted already? l.Fecha is a DateTime as it seems:

```
var items = from item in db.VENTA_PLATILLOS.Select(l => l.Fecha)
     .Distinct()
     .OrderByDescending(x => x)
    let dateday = item.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
    select new SelectListItem {Value = dateday, Text = dateday, Selected = result.Day == item.Day};
listdate.AddRange(items);
```